# Publishing release notes to Wiki during build in ADO pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, wiki, release-notes

I generate release note automatically when ever the build is triggered. My aim is to create a wiki page from the release note. I followed the powershell script on https://scatteredcode.net/publishing-release-notes-to-tfs-vsts-wiki-during-release/

The script ran successfully but the wiki sub page did not get created. The aim is to create a sub page "test" under the PartsUnlimitedWiki page.

wikiPath: [https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/MyDevOpsProject/_apis/wiki/wikis/MyDevOpsProject_wiki/pages?path=PartsUnlimitedWiki/test&api-version=6.0"](https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/MyDevOpsProject/_apis/wiki/wikis/MyDevOpsProject_wiki/pages?path=PartsUnlimitedWiki/test&api-version=6.0%22)

PowerShell Script

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with below PowerShell script, and it can work will to create/update the sub-page with the content. You can reference it to update your script.

```
$pat = "{Personal Access Token}"
$base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $base64Token))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wiki-name}/pages?path=/parent-page-name/sub-page-name&api-version=7.0"

$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("path/to/release-notes.md")
$body = @{content = $content} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

When you run the script in Azure Pipelines, the value of authorization token can be either your PAT (Personal Access Token) or the [**`System.AccessToken`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken) (Job access token). You can follow the documentation "[**Job access tokens**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)" to check and assign **`System.AccessToken`** with the required permissions to access Wiki.